# Can I deploy an app built on SAP Cloud SDK to Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

We build a SCP native java application based on SAP cloud SDK. if we later on migrate to SCP kubernete env., would the app runs without migration? if changes needed, how much effort would it be? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Applications using the Java libraries of the SAP Cloud SDK can also run on a local machine and, as a consequence, as part of an application running in a container in Kubernetes. Additionally, the SDK already today provides [abstractions that allow to run the same code on Cloud Foundry and Neo](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/19/deep-dive-3-cloud-platform-abstractions-in-the-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk/) when accessing services of SAP Cloud Platform.

I cannot yet say how the access to specific functionality of SAP Cloud Platform works in Cloud Foundry versus a future Kubernetes environment, but this should be the blueprint.